# A way to redirect stderr AND get name of the failed script in a series of script commands in bash?

Tags: python, bash, shell, command, stderr

I'm setting up an email notification system where I want to save failed commands (edit: failed scripts) in a .txt file and once a day I have a python script to send out an email containing all the failed jobs.

It currently looks like either:
script1.py && script2.py && ... && scriptN.py 2>> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt" or
script1.sh && script2.sh arg1 && .. && scriptN.sh 2>> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt"

Some scripts takes arguments. It seems like it works fine with the redirecting of stderr, but I need to pipe the name of the failed script + the string "DONE" into "failedscripts.txt" as well.

My failed tries:

script1 && script2 && .. && scriptN 2>> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt" || echo $_,"done">> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt"

script1 && script2 && .. && scriptN 2>> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt" ; echo $_,"done">> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt"

script1 && script2 && .. && scriptN 2>> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt" && echo $_,"done">> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt"

But this surely just pipes "failedscripts.txt,done" to my failedscripts.txt....

Comment: What do you mean by _the name of the failed command_? There are _N_ names in the compound command.

Comment: I mean the failed script. For example if script1 and script2 give exit code 0 and script3 gives exit code != 0 , then I need the name of that script (e.g. "script3.py" or "script3.sh") to be piped to my failedcommands.txt

Comment: I edited my questions, hopefully it makes more sense now. I need the "script3" to be piped to "failedscripts.txt" along the string "done" and with the stderr obtain from 2>> "/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt"

Comment: Well behaved programs report their name as the leading information in the error message.  For example (on a Mac), running `ls -:` generates two lines of output on `stderr`:— `ls: illegal option -- :` and `usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]`.  That's normal.  If the commands you're running aren't as civilized and are within your sphere of influence, you should request that they _do_ output the command name as part of any error message written to `stderr`. (Of course, there's also an assumption that they write to `stderr`; if they write to `stdout`, they're broken.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way which doesn't give exactly the output format you wish, but does indicate *the failed script* by writing every executed *script* to the file, so that the last one before *DONE* is the failed one:

```
(set -x; script1 && script2 && … && scriptN) 2>/tmp/$$ || (cat /tmp/$$; echo DONE) >>/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt; rm /tmp/$$
```

Comment: But it will only give me output if one of the scripts fail, right? It is to implemented in our crontab, so I don't know all the scripts nor the order they are executed in.

Comment: Right, it will as you say. Do you want standard error output also if the scripts don't fail?

Comment: No, just when failing is perfect.It almost works! On my python scripts it works, but on my .sh scripts that consists of sql-scripts it does not output to my failedscripts.txt...I think however that it works if change || to && in .sh cases. any thoughts on doing so?

Comment: I don't think so - to _change || to &&_ would mean that the standard error output and DONE are written to `failedscripts.txt` only if the compound command succeeds (allegedly). If now with the `||` _it does not output to my failedscripts.txt_ (not even the `DONE`) in case of error, we can infer that those failing _.sh scripts that consists of sql-scripts_ do not return an error exit status, so pretending they did not fail. Can you modify those scripts so that they don't conceal their failure?

Comment: I will definitely try to see if we can modify our scripts.. However, it seems like the problem is more comprehensive. It worked in my testing environment, but when I implemented it in our crontab it does not work. I cant even run _echo "hello" >> /home/mydir/failedscripts.txt_ .. and I seriously have no idea why. It still runs all the scripts correctly, but it is as if it doesnt allow for any piping or anything.  I've tried /bin/echo and putting it all in a script.sh that takes all the "script1 && .. && scriptN" as argument.. Nothing works. Any suggestions?? Kinda desperate haha

Comment: Interesting - Is the crontab of another user who isn't permitted to write to _/home/mydir/failedscripts.txt_? You could try with `id >/tmp/somefile`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, I have not been at work since (student assistant). I am very happy to let you know that it works - some permission issues was resolved and the script works great. THANK YOU SO MUCH!